# Animation in CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

What links would I need to have this animation work properly on any other IDE's? Does anyone know? The animation works fine here: https://codepen.io/ksu/pen/VwZQmGR

```js
new WOW().init();

/* AUTHOR LINK */
$('.about-me-img img, .authorWindowWrapper').hover(function() {
  $('.authorWindowWrapper').stop().fadeIn('fast').find('p').addClass('trans');
}, function() {
  //$('.authorWindowWrapper').stop().css('display', 'none').find('p').removeClass('trans');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Open Sans, "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
div,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ul,
ol,
li,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
pre,
form,
p,
blockquote,
th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  direction: ltr;
}

.sectionClass {
  padding: 80px 0px 50px 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: rgb(249, 249, 249);
}

.row {
  width: 980px;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.sectiontitle {
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.sectiontitle h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #222;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.headerLine {
  width: 160px;
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #101F2E;
}

.fullWidth {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
/********************************/
/*  SECTION WORK EXPERIENCE
********************************/

#work-experience .sectiontitle .headerLine {
  width: 280px;
}

#work-experience .headerline {
  width: 280px;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline {
  margin: 60px 30px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10px;
  background: #324454;
  left: 13%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline li:last-child:before {
  content: initial;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  padding-right: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span:first-child {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #bdd0db;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span:last-child {
  font-size: 2.9em;
  color: #3594cb;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(odd) .cbp_tmtime span:last-child {
  color: #6cbfee;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel {
  margin: 0 0 15px 25%;
  background: rgba(50, 68, 84, 1);
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(odd) .cbp_tmlabel {
  background: #2B3A48;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel h3 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel h4 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel h4 i {
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel:after {
  right: 100%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-right-color: rgba(50, 68, 84, 1);
  border-width: 10px;
  top: 70px;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(odd) .cbp_tmlabel:after {
  border-right-color: #2B3A48;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmicon {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 3%;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 40px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  position: absolute;
  color: #151515;
  background: #324454;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 8%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -25px;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline li {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  position: relative;
}

.sectionClassProject {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  /* background: #f7f7f7; */
  
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 80px 1.875em 3.125em;
}

.projectParagraph {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', serif;
}

.projectParagraphLink {
  font-size: 15px !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  margin-top: 50px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: right;
}

.projectParagraphLink a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.cbp_tmicon img {
  width: 100%;
}

.faPra {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.label {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.date {
  color: #BFC3C7;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 20px;
}

.date i {
  margin-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .cbp_tmtimeline:before {
    display: none;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel {
    margin: 30px 0 70px 0;
    padding: 50px 30px 30px 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 95%;
    float: left;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel:after {
    right: auto;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(50, 68, 84);
    top: -20px;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(odd) .cbp_tmlabel:after {
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(43, 58, 72);
    left: 65px;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(even) .cbp_tmlabel:after {
    right: 65px;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(odd) .cbp_tmicon {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: auto;
    margin: 0px 5px 0 0px;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(even) .cbp_tmicon {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    left: auto;
    margin: 0px 5px 0 0px;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span:last-child {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 32em) {
  .cbp-ntaccordion {
    font-size: 70%;
  }
}
/********************************/
/*  AUTHOR LINK
********************************/

footer {
  z-index: 100;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

footer p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200px);
  transform: translateX(-200px);
  margin: 0;
}

footer .authorWindow a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer p strong {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.about-me-img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  left: 10px;
  /* bottom: 30px; */
  
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #4A5F67;
}

.about-me-img img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.authorWindow {
  width: 600px;
  background: #101F2E;
  padding: 22px 20px 22px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.authorWindowWrapper {
  display: none;
  left: 110px;
  bottom: -20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

.trans {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .authorWindow {
    width: 210px;
  }
  .authorWindowWrapper {
    bottom: -170px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  footer p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="workexperience" class="sectionClass">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="sectiontitle">
      <h2>Work experience</h2>
      <span class="headerLine"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="fullWidth eight columns">
      <ul class="cbp_tmtimeline">
        <li>
          <div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-phone">
            <i class="faPra fa-briefcase"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="cbp_tmlabel wow fadeInRight animated">
            <h3>Web developer</h3>
            <div class="date">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>April 2014 - Current
            </div>
            <h4><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>Davic Company, Bratislava</h4>
            <p class="projectParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit obcaecati ipsa quae, iusto laudantium qui, nisi eum modi perspiciatis quasi facilis corporis iure soluta enim incidunt itaque aspernatur sequi tempora.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-screen">
            <i class="faPra fa-briefcase"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="cbp_tmlabel wow fadeInRight animated">
            <h3>Web designer</h3>
            <h4><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>Fannous Company, Prague</h4>
            <div class="date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>June 2012 - April 2014</div>
            <p class="projectParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt quasi perspiciatis, aliquid sed maiores accusamus. Adipisci quidem nostrum quos quae doloremque esse a, ipsum earum, recusandae omnis dignissimos et sint.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-mail">
            <i class="faPra fa-briefcase"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="cbp_tmlabel wow fadeInRight animated">
            <h3>Web designer</h3>
            <h4><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>Techixs Company, London</h4>
            <div class="date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>November 2009 - June 2012</div>
            <p class="projectParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla labore atque alias ipsa, nam quod rerum repellat cumque, aliquam sequi vitae voluptatibus cum soluta incidunt tempore accusamus eius sed excepturi!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora natus veritatis aperiam repellendus dolor vel, expedita assumenda eos, mollitia quae ullam esse voluptas vero. Dolores culpa eaque vitae eum quibusdam?</p>

          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-phone">
            <i class="faPra fa-briefcase"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="cbp_tmlabel wow fadeInRight animated">
            <h3>Freelancer</h3>
            <div class="date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Januar 2006 - November 2009</div>
            <p class="projectParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse iusto, possimus hic at quisquam, incidunt illo asperiores et nobis, qui nulla consequatur molestiae quibusdam expedita dignissimos? Iste eum velit quos.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <div class="about-me-img">
    <a href="http://jakubtursky.studenthosting.sk/?lang=en">
      <img src="https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/722e/qk13jrjdq7z45k1zg.jpg" alt="Jakub Turský" width="110px" height="110px">
    </a>
    <div class="authorWindowWrapper">
      <div class="authorWindow">
        <p>Work experiences
          <br> Created by <a href="http://jakubtursky.studenthosting.sk/?lang=en"><strong>Jakub Turský</strong></a>
          <br> For next info about me you can visit me site ( click on my image, name, or copy url www.jakubtursky.studenthosting.sk/?lang=en )
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

But if I were to use it on any other IDE, then what header links would I need for it? It does not seem to also work here, since WOW is not defined, but this is my first time working with this library so I'm unsure.

These are the errors I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5za3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,900&amp;amp" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.6/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
```

```js
new WOW().init();

/* AUTHOR LINK */
$('.about-me-img img, .authorWindowWrapper').hover(function() {
  $('.authorWindowWrapper').stop().fadeIn('fast').find('p').addClass('trans');
}, function() {
  //$('.authorWindowWrapper').stop().css('display', 'none').find('p').removeClass('trans');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Open Sans, "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #666;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
div,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ul,
ol,
li,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
pre,
form,
p,
blockquote,
th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  direction: ltr;
}

.sectionClass {
  padding: 80px 0px 50px 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: rgb(249, 249, 249);
}

.row {
  width: 980px;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.sectiontitle {
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 20px;
}

.sectiontitle h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #222;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.headerLine {
  width: 160px;
  height: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #101F2E;
}

.fullWidth {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  float: none;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
/********************************/
/*  SECTION WORK EXPERIENCE
********************************/

#work-experience .sectiontitle .headerLine {
  width: 280px;
}

#work-experience .headerline {
  width: 280px;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline {
  margin: 60px 30px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10px;
  background: #324454;
  left: 13%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline li:last-child:before {
  content: initial;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime {
  display: block;
  width: 25%;
  padding-right: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span:first-child {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  color: #bdd0db;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span:last-child {
  font-size: 2.9em;
  color: #3594cb;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(odd) .cbp_tmtime span:last-child {
  color: #6cbfee;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel {
  margin: 0 0 15px 25%;
  background: rgba(50, 68, 84, 1);
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(odd) .cbp_tmlabel {
  background: #2B3A48;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel h3 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel h4 {
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel h4 i {
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel:after {
  right: 100%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-right-color: rgba(50, 68, 84, 1);
  border-width: 10px;
  top: 70px;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(odd) .cbp_tmlabel:after {
  border-right-color: #2B3A48;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmicon {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 3%;
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 40px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  position: absolute;
  color: #151515;
  background: #324454;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 8%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -25px;
}

.cbp_tmtimeline li {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  position: relative;
}

.sectionClassProject {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  /* background: #f7f7f7; */
  
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 80px 1.875em 3.125em;
}

.projectParagraph {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0.5em 0 0;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', serif;
}

.projectParagraphLink {
  font-size: 15px !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  margin-top: 50px !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: right;
}

.projectParagraphLink a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.cbp_tmicon img {
  width: 100%;
}

.faPra {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  line-height: 150px;
}

.label {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.date {
  color: #BFC3C7;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 20px;
}

.date i {
  margin-right: 8px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .cbp_tmtimeline:before {
    display: none;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel {
    margin: 30px 0 70px 0;
    padding: 50px 30px 30px 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 95%;
    float: left;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmlabel:after {
    right: auto;
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(50, 68, 84);
    top: -20px;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(odd) .cbp_tmlabel:after {
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: rgb(43, 58, 72);
    left: 65px;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(even) .cbp_tmlabel:after {
    right: 65px;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(odd) .cbp_tmicon {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: auto;
    margin: 0px 5px 0 0px;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li:nth-child(even) .cbp_tmicon {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    left: auto;
    margin: 0px 5px 0 0px;
  }
  .cbp_tmtimeline > li .cbp_tmtime span:last-child {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 32em) {
  .cbp-ntaccordion {
    font-size: 70%;
  }
}
/********************************/
/*  AUTHOR LINK
********************************/

footer {
  z-index: 100;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

footer p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  width: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200px);
  transform: translateX(-200px);
  margin: 0;
}

footer .authorWindow a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer p strong {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.about-me-img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  left: 10px;
  /* bottom: 30px; */
  
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #4A5F67;
}

.about-me-img img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.authorWindow {
  width: 600px;
  background: #101F2E;
  padding: 22px 20px 22px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.authorWindowWrapper {
  display: none;
  left: 110px;
  bottom: -20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

.trans {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .authorWindow {
    width: 210px;
  }
  .authorWindowWrapper {
    bottom: -170px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  footer p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,900&amp;amp" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.6/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>
<div id="workexperience" class="sectionClass">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="sectiontitle">
      <h2>Work experience</h2>
      <span class="headerLine"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="fullWidth eight columns">
      <ul class="cbp_tmtimeline">
        <li>
          <div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-phone">
            <i class="faPra fa-briefcase"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="cbp_tmlabel wow fadeInRight animated">
            <h3>Web developer</h3>
            <div class="date">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>April 2014 - Current
            </div>
            <h4><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>Davic Company, Bratislava</h4>
            <p class="projectParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit obcaecati ipsa quae, iusto laudantium qui, nisi eum modi perspiciatis quasi facilis corporis iure soluta enim incidunt itaque aspernatur sequi tempora.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-screen">
            <i class="faPra fa-briefcase"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="cbp_tmlabel wow fadeInRight animated">
            <h3>Web designer</h3>
            <h4><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>Fannous Company, Prague</h4>
            <div class="date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>June 2012 - April 2014</div>
            <p class="projectParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt quasi perspiciatis, aliquid sed maiores accusamus. Adipisci quidem nostrum quos quae doloremque esse a, ipsum earum, recusandae omnis dignissimos et sint.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-mail">
            <i class="faPra fa-briefcase"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="cbp_tmlabel wow fadeInRight animated">
            <h3>Web designer</h3>
            <h4><i class="fa fa-flag"></i>Techixs Company, London</h4>
            <div class="date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>November 2009 - June 2012</div>
            <p class="projectParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla labore atque alias ipsa, nam quod rerum repellat cumque, aliquam sequi vitae voluptatibus cum soluta incidunt tempore accusamus eius sed excepturi!Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
              consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora natus veritatis aperiam repellendus dolor vel, expedita assumenda eos, mollitia quae ullam esse voluptas vero. Dolores culpa eaque vitae eum quibusdam?</p>

          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="cbp_tmicon cbp_tmicon-phone">
            <i class="faPra fa-briefcase"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="cbp_tmlabel wow fadeInRight animated">
            <h3>Freelancer</h3>
            <div class="date"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Januar 2006 - November 2009</div>
            <p class="projectParagraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse iusto, possimus hic at quisquam, incidunt illo asperiores et nobis, qui nulla consequatur molestiae quibusdam expedita dignissimos? Iste eum velit quos.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer>
  <div class="about-me-img">
    <a href="http://jakubtursky.studenthosting.sk/?lang=en">
      <img src="https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/722e/qk13jrjdq7z45k1zg.jpg" alt="Jakub Turský" width="110px" height="110px">
    </a>
    <div class="authorWindowWrapper">
      <div class="authorWindow">
        <p>Work experiences
          <br> Created by <a href="http://jakubtursky.studenthosting.sk/?lang=en"><strong>Jakub Turský</strong></a>
          <br> For next info about me you can visit me site ( click on my image, name, or copy url www.jakubtursky.studenthosting.sk/?lang=en )
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: it gives an error when you run it here

Comment: it works almost

Comment: I get one error now. Wow is not defined

Comment: @HelloWorld Does it work in IDE?

Comment: Nope, it gives "Wow not defined" error

Comment: it says, "Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined
    at experience.js:1:1"

Comment: @HelloWorld add WOW reference
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.0/wow.min.js"></script>`
 before where `new WOW` is specified. Does that help?

Comment: you mean I put that in the JS file or HTML file?

Comment: @HelloWorld in html above the path to your js containing `new WOW`

Comment: nope, it doesnt work

Comment: https://wowjs.uk/docs.html check this doc  "WOW is not defined" this error is because you have to  add wow.min.js file to your project before calling wow function

Comment: you can experiment with it in the code that is sent as answer, since it shows the error there too

Comment: “Script error” is what browsers send to the onerror callback when an error originates from a JavaScript file served from a different origin (different domain, port, or protocol). It's painful because even though there's an error occurring, you don't know what the error is, nor from which code it's originating.

Comment: Do I create a new file named "wow.js"?

Comment: @HelloWorld Nope add `<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.6/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.0/wow.min.js"></script>` before `<script src="/path/to/your.js"></script>`

Comment: @HelloWorld Does it throw error when running `new WOW().init();` on Chrome console during runtime?

Comment: @HelloWorld changed Wow.min.js version. Please check once with new snippet

Comment: @HelloWorld If you need the file locally as in /app/js/wow.min.js as in your error, you need to download the cdn file (open [wow.min.js cdn](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.0/wow.min.js) and right click,Save As... ) to your `js` folder

Comment: @SHAHILMISHRA I changed wow version to 1.1.2 and it is working

Comment: @HelloWorld I fixed the Script error in my snippet. Use the new code in your IDE and check once